# problem in nopcommerce :Components don't load in product.template.simple when call from new route

Tags: nopcommerce-4.0

I call product.template.simple view from new action in product controller . But when page load , components like as cloudzoom and quick -tabs don't load

Comment: Please add some more information and code, by that others will get an idea, also mentioned what you have tried?

Comment: Please explain in detail so we can assist on your question.